# Postgres performance using A Union B vs Where A OR B

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am wondering if unions will operate at the same speed as where clauses.

Note: I do put indexes on any relevant columns

e.g.

```
-- Using where or condition
select group, name from jobs where group = 'a' or group = 'b'

-- Using union's to achieve the same result
select group, name from jobs where group = 'a'
union
select group, name from jobs where group = 'a'
```

In the example above is one technique going to be faster?, or would they both perform at the same speed

The reason I ask is that I need to do fuzzy matches using either `similarity, trigrams or ts_vectors` in which the filter condition that actually matched needs be returned so that I know how a particular row was found.

e.g.

```
-- Using where or condition
select description from jobs where 
    description = to_tsvector('english', description) @@ to_tsquery('english', 'ability <-> to <-> motivate <-> others')
    or
    description = to_tsvector('english', description) @@ to_tsquery('english', 'excellent <-> organisational <-> skills')

-- NOTE: When using (where OR) I have no way of telling which condition actually matched 

-- Using union's to achieve the same result
select 'ability to motivate others' as search_term, description
 from jobs
 where description = to_tsvector('english', description) @@ to_tsquery('english', 'ability <-> to <-> motivate <-> others')
union
or
select 'excellent organisational skills' as search_term, description
from jobs
where description = to_tsvector('english', description) @@ to_tsquery('english', 'excellent <-> organisational <-> skills')
```

Comment: "In the example above is one technique going to be faster?, or would they both perform at the same speed" is the column `group` indexed.. And i assume the second query in the union should match `b` and not `a`

Answer (score 3):

`union` does *not* operate at the same speed as a `where` clause.  A `union` incurs overhead for removing duplicates, which often means sorting data.  That is why `union all` is preferred, if that can achieve the same result set.

That said, sometimes the subqueries used with the `union`/`union all` can be optimized better than the same query using `or` in a `where` or `on` clause.

So, it is not possible to say that `union` is always bad in this circumstance.  A reasonable viewpoint is that `union` incurs extra overhead.  If the subqueries can be optimized, this overhead may not be important, but more often than not, `union` will hinder performance.

Answer (score 0):

Just to complement Gordon's answer that I find excellent, as a rule of thumb a `UNION` (or `UNION ALL`) will require multiple passes over the table (or index of it) to retrieve each subset of rows before consolidating them.

On the other hand, a single `WHERE` will require a single pass over the table (or its index) to produce the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Where clauses filter a query, whereas Unions append and aggregate multiple queries. In most (if not all) cases a Where clause is going to be faster than a Union of two wheres accomplishing the same thing.

If this isn't immediately clear, here are two images for comparison from explain/analyze in pgAdmin.
[image]

The above image illustrates a Union operation. See how the table is scanned twice?

Now observe the following image:

[image]

Much simpler, don't you think? Because postgres only has to scan the data once, then filter down the result set, your simple where clause operates much more smoothly.

As for your other problem, you could attempt to use grouping, condition matching or subselects, although all of these methods are going to increase the computation time slightly (in the case of subselects possibly eliminating the advantage gained by not using the Union, depending on your data structure).

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to enumerate (and remember) the matched conditions.
Simplified example with text-fields instead of ts_vectors:

---

```
\i tmp.sql

create table persons( id serial primary key, hair text, eyes text);

insert into persons( hair , eyes)  VALUES
 ( 'blonde', 'blue' ) , ( 'blonde', 'brown' ) , ( 'blonde', 'green' )
, ( 'brown', 'blue' ) , ( 'brown', 'blue' ) , ( 'brown', 'green' )
, ( 'red', 'brown' ) , ( 'red', 'blue' ) , ( 'red', 'green' )
        ;


SELECT p.*
        , x.redhaired,x.blueeyed
FROM persons p
JOIN (SELECT q.id
        -- set flags for matched conditions
        , case when hair = 'red' THEN True else False end AS redhaired
        , case when eyes = 'blue' THEN True else False end AS blueeyed
        FROM persons q
        WHERE q.hair = 'red' OR q.eyes = 'blue' -- <<-- composite search-clause
        ) x ON x.id = p.id -- rejoin on PK
        ;
```

---

Instead of the boolean `case ...` expressions you probably want to select some `ts_xxx(...)` string-distance measure, but the mechanism is the same. (the hard part is avoiding duplication of the expressions...)